# Cplex callable library

Tags: cplex

I am trying to compile very old source code which uses cplex functions from the callable C library (cplex 4.0).

Some of the functions seem to have been renamed/replaced...

Can anyone tell me the functions that have replaced

CPXloadlp

CPXloadbase

CPXgetcolspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CPXXreadcopyprob and CPXreadcopyprob**

The routine CPXXreadcopyprob/CPXreadcopyprob reads an MPS, LP, or SAV file into an existing CPLEX problem object.

**CPXXreadcopybase and CPXreadcopybase**

The routine CPXXreadcopybase/CPXreadcopybase reads a basis from a BAS file, and copies that basis into a CPLEX problem object.

**CPXXsolution and CPXsolution**

The routine CPXXsolution/CPXsolution accesses the solution values